# Handle back command in custom ContextMenuHandler

Tags: chromium, cefsharp

I have implemented a custom `ContextMenuHandler`:

```
public bool OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
{
    if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26501)
    {
        // custom logic
        return true;
    }

    if (commandId == CefMenuCommand.Back)
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (chromiumWebBrowser.CanGoBack) chromiumWebBrowser.Back();
        });

    }

    return true;
}
```

The custom command works as expected. However, the *Back*-command doesn't work. The thread doesn't have access to the browser instance:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

Omitting the dispatching logic doesn't solve the problem.

1. Do I need to explicitly handle the *Back*-command using the if-statement (will be refactored to swicth-case, no worries)
2. If yes, how?
3. In general, how can I get the dispatcher of the web browser instance?

Comment: Using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher won't always return the UI dispatcher, cast IWebBrowser to it's concrete implementation like https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/Handlers/MenuHandler.cs#L52

Comment: If you don't need custom commands then see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/Handlers/MenuHandler.cs#L62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not include the `Back`-command in the switch-case and return false instead.

```
public bool OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
{
    if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26501)
    {
        // custom logic
        return true;
    } 

    return false;
}
```